# How python logging get it's configuration

Tags: python, logging

I used to **Python logging**, it works fine.  The `logging.basicConfig(...)` set in one module (a `some.py` file), then we can use `logging` every where.  Obviously, **logging** is global.

The question is how logging find it's settings, when we not call the `module` where *basicConfig(...)* appeared (in *some.py* file )?  Is logging scan all the packages?

Even the `logging.basicConfig(...)` put into an `any.py` and the module (`any.py`) never get imported, or not used anywhere, the logging setting **take effect**!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand logging you have dive into Python's standard library sources.

Here is the trick:

```
#/usr/lib/python3.2/logging/__init__.py
...
root = RootLogger(WARNING)
Logger.root = root
Logger.manager = Manager(Logger.root)
...

# and 
def basicConfig(**kwargs):
    ...
        hdlr = StreamHandler(stream)
        fs = kwargs.get("format", BASIC_FORMAT)
        dfs = kwargs.get("datefmt", None)
        style = kwargs.get("style", '%')
        fmt = Formatter(fs, dfs, style)
        hdlr.setFormatter(fmt)
        root.addHandler(hdlr)
```

So, when you call `basicconfig()` with certain parameters, `root` logger is set. 
Finally `getLogger`:

```
def getLogger(name=None):
    """
    Return a logger with the specified name, creating it if necessary.

    If no name is specified, return the root logger.
    """
    if name:
        return Logger.manager.getLogger(name)
    else:
        return root
```

Comment: +1 for clear code samples.  Still wondering when *basicConfig* get called.

Answer (score 2):

I think there is no magic scanning here.

- Try to test it this way in a separate `test` directory:

  ```
  test/main.py:
      import logging
      logging.info('test')
  ```

  test/any.py:
      import logging
      logging.basicConfig(filename='test.log', level=logging.INFO)

  python main.py

  **Result:** NO `test.log` file.
- Now let's update the test:

  ```
  test/main.py:
      import logging
      import any
      logging.info('test')
  ```

  python main.py

  **Result:** new `test.log` file with `INFO:root:test` string inside.
- So I guess that `any.py` in your case is imported somehow,
  despite your expectations.

  You may find the way `any.py` is imported easily,
  just add few lines there:

  ```
  test/any.py:
      from traceback import print_stack
      print_stack()
      ...
  ```

  python main.py

  **Result:**

  ```
  File "main.py", line 2, in 
      import any
  File "any.py", line 2, in 
      print_stack()
  ```

  This stack shows that `any.py` is imported from `main.py`.

  I hope you will find where it is imported from in your case.

Comment: Yes, `no magics` happens when it put into a new place.  In my old project, I *do* put the logging setting **logging.basicConfig()** into a *new and not-used* file, and it *do* show up.  Only thing possible to scan the file is the testing tool, pytest in case.